# Can't write file to internal storage Android

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I am trying to save a user history to the internal storage, which seems to work (no error) :

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(userHistory);
        historyFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "MyApp" + File.separator + "UserHistory.json");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(historyFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(json.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
```

But when I try to open it I got a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
        InputStream inputStream = assets.open(historyFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should not use assets but FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, I managed to find an answer, I use :

```
String userHistoryJson = fileToString(historyFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

With the function below :

```
public String fileToString(String fileName) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (fileName);  // 2nd line
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, n));
        }
        String json =  new String(fileContent);
        return json;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```